# Is it possible to nest Angular2 applications

Tags: angular

Suppose I want to build an Angular2 Application that can be inserted into third-party pages. The third-party page might already use Angular2 (possible in a different version). Would it be possible to bootstrap my Angular 2 application inside the third-party application.

```
<body>
  <third-party-angular-app>
    <third-party-component>
      <my-angular-app>
      </my-angular-app>
    </third-party-component>
  </third-party-angular-app>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, Angular is capable of bootstrapping multiple applications.
It is designed for that, here are several hints:

In this [line of code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/application_ref.ts#L422) we can see multiple **root components**, each root component is an app hence multiple apps.

In this [line of code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/application_ref.ts#L576) we can see there are multiple **root** change detectors (hence forEach). A component has 1 change detector, this is true for the root component as well (MyApp), so multiple change detectors hint multiple root components, i.e: multiple apps.

I created a plunker sample to show that it works

```
https://embed.plnkr.co/37vJiq/
```

Comment: But this way it is not possible to bootstrap one application inside another, at least I would expect serious troubles.

Comment: Why is that? I see no issues here.
Each app should have a different Zone, you can also bootstrap outside of the zone, if you want to.

Here is an example of bootstrapping inside a component, i.e inside the app: https://embed.plnkr.co/bb4QUo/

Comment: I meant because an Angular2 app needs full control of it's DOM, but it seems you're right.

Comment: I agree that it's an unknown territory. What happens when you use the same component in both apps? What if this shared component is used as a child component inside App2 but the template originated in App1. complicated stuff yet edge cases and one might consider them abuse :)

Comment: Oops. It looks like the links here do not resolve. Can you update the links or include the code inline? Thanks!