# Angular2 : How can I create a modular application?

Tags: angular

I need to create a modular application based on the following principles :

1. **Core of the application**: a set of services/components usable everywhere in the application (the core of the application). It will contain for instance the identification of the user, the capacity to log events, the global design with SASS, a file manager, a print manager ... All the mandatory elements will be developed in the core.
2. **Some optionally plugins** that can be added to that core. For instance, this will bring some new functionalities to the core application or adapt the generic core to a specific use case. The plugins have to use the elements of the core (for instance the plugin log events with the log manager of the core).
3. The core **is executed first and load existing plugins** at startup.
4. The core is designed, developed and compiled **alone** without any plugins.
5. Each plugin is designed, developed and compiled alone but can use some services/components of the core application.
6. I can **install or remove plugins** according to user needs.

As far as I understand for the moment, I note sure that Angular2+ can fulfill such a concept :

- Create the core in components and plugins inside other components of the same module (angular2+ basic use case): no complaint
- Create the core in a Module and plugins inside different modules: no complaint because I still need to compile everything together and the result is built inside a global js file.
- Create several angular apps nested together (based on that solution: [Is it possible to nest Angular2 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441867/is-it-possible-to-nest-angular2-applications)) but it seems that solution is not really under control.

I don't really have other ideas, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I thought that's what [modules](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules) and [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) are made for. Did you take a look at that?

Comment: `I'm not sure that Angular 2+ can fullfill such concept` : well it can. In fact, any JS framework can. The decisive factor is how you code, not what you use. Just [read the documentation](https://angular.io/) to see if you like Angular, and if you don't, then simply do not use it.

Comment: To answer your three counterpoints : Angular can manage plugins and core modules. Just create a module per plugin and you'll be fine. You can defer the loading of certain scripts until you reach a particular URL, so you can separate the plugins from the dist bundle. And you don't need to create separate applications.

Comment: @peter : I have the feeling that you understand my question as a criticize to angular2. My question is clearly not a criticize as I already develop a web app based on that framework and I really liked it. The problem is just that I don't know for the moment how to implement my need.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I can install or remove plugins according to user needs.*"? In particular, what do you mean by "*install*"? What is a plugin in this context? It's not entirely clear what you're asking. As far as I understand, you should be able to use Angulars module-capabilities and achieve what you want unless I understand something wrong here.

Comment: Well, I had a look at answers and modules (even lazy loading) is not the solution as it doesn't answer to constraint 5.

If I understand - but maybe I don't (and that's why I need help) - with modules my whole application will be built/compiled together (core and plugins included) while I need to manage them separately.

I'm not sure to be clear enough so I take examples : 
 - core application : Firefox, Notepad++, Chrome
 - plugins : addons, extensions, plugins.
In these cases, the core application is standalone and you create plugin independently (compil, resources, developers ...)

Comment: Let's say it in differents words : If I manage plugins with different modules, what is the result of the compilation ?
Will I have a single application packed on common JS files or will I have a set of JS files for each module ?

Comment: After a full search today, I may have found a solution here : https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/05/04/microservice-clients-with-web-components-using-angular-elements-dreams-of-the-near-future.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some investigations, the solution of my question is based on @Angular/elements that provides :

1. Lazy loading to avoid having everything load at startup
2. Creation of independants libraries that may be developped and build separatly

More Informations here :

- https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/05/04/microservice-clients-with-web-components-using-angular-elements-dreams-of-the-near-future.aspx
- https://angular.io/guide/elements
- https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Answer (score 0):

Modularity will depend on your coding skill, with Angular start this way:

1. learn to create lazy loaded modules (has some cons - if you wan't to create menu from routing config automatically, but otherwise it's ok)
2. split routing - in app-routes i do have route to lazy loaded modules, rest of the routing define inside the sub-module (or it's module)
3. try to pack related things together
4. never use magic strings, use consts/enums
5. i do rely on the DTO model at binding, if you use model driven approach, just make sure the controls are named the same as the properties. i do push just the DTO (data) into the component, my code outside that sub-component does not have any assumption on how the sub-component is coded (separating of concerns, clear code)
6. find a way to handle complex UI validation and validation error displaying in an easily feasible way [this is one of the biggest pain of all and every sample you will see around will be non-reusable, too specific...at least it was so when I solved this issue]
7. make sure you use fluent design approach (bootstrap, always considering that viewport size might change or someone on browser is using your code)
8. buy (or use a free) UI library bundle, best if written in angular (so not just wrapped). the one Telerik has helped me lot to understand how to create angular components
9. and if components, learn what ControlValueAccessor is, so you can create ngModel bindable components!

Comment: This was when I started to exp. with validation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190396/how-to-do-angular2-4-validation-with-3rd-party-js-components